# View exported console coloured logs

Tags: linux, console, stdout

Is there a way to view exported coloured logs as in console (with colour)?

My program uses colour coding for errors, warnings, etc. If I redirect output of my program to file.log, I get records like:

> [32m[1m(INF)[0m /environment/converter: State map: [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 ][0m
>
> [32m[1m(INF)[0m /environment/converter: Action map: [ -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ][0m
>
> [32m[1m(INF)[0m PyEnv: Observation dims: 15[0m
>
> [32m[1m(INF)[0m PyEnv: Action dims: 6[0m
>
> Random seed  None
>
> [32m[1m(INF)[0m GRL seed 1428[0m

Now I want to see file.log, but without colour codes or even better with colours preserved.

I have tried nano, vi and gedit but they all do not do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas if you're still wondering for a good way to do this.

- A text editor won't be able to read the color codes, as those are Bash specific. However, `cat` works because it can interpret the color codes. However, the way you're storing the colors *isn't formatted correctly* in the first place.

I'm  not sure how you are writing into your log file, but I echoed your example and redirected the output into a file. I didn't see colors either. The reason is that you have to escape every square bracket for the codes to be interpreted by Bash.

So the way that I escaped the brackets is by manually adding \e before every square bracket and using echo -e to evaluate the escape characters:

```
`echo -e "\e[32m\e[1m(INF)\e[0m /environment/converter: State map: [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 ]\e[0m`                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
`\e[32m\e[1m(INF)\e[0m /environment/converter: Action map: [ -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]\e[0m`                                                                                                                                                             
`\e[32m\e[1m(INF)\e[0m PyEnv: Observation dims: 15\e[0m`                                                                                                                                                                                                      
`\e[32m\e[1m(INF)\e[0m PyEnv: Action dims: 6\e[0m`                                                                                                                                                                                                            
`Random seed None`                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
`\e[32m\e[1m(INF)\e[0m GRL seed 1428\e[0m " > example.txt`
```

Now when I open the file with `cat` I see correctly colored text:

[image: Screenshot of using cat on the correctly formatted output in the command line]

The color codes are now stored and escaped correctly in the .txt file:

`^[[32m[1m(INF)[0m GRL seed 1428^[[0m`
vs

`[32m[1m(INF)[0m GRL seed 1428[0m`

- An alternative solution is to use a package like [Ansi Html Adapter (Aha)](https://github.com/theZiz/aha).

It will produce HTML instead of plain text. Then you can open the output in your browser, and it would have the right color coding.

However, you would meet with the same problem. If the color codes aren't escaped correctly, the output is not going to be colored.

I ran the following command to convert the correctly formatted text to HTML:

`aha -f example.txt > example.html`

Here's the result in the browser:

[image: Aha output in the browser]

You can find more info on how to use colors in bash in this [Bash Tips article](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting).